# How can I open a popup window using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have this sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/bac8qdq1/

**HTML:**

```
<a id="OpenDialog" href="#">Click here to open dialog</a>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
    <p>test</p>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#OpenDialog").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            height: 590,
            width: 1005
        });
    });
});
```

I want that when a user clicks on the link to open, a new window pops up with a text area inside.

I tried the above code, but unfortunately it did not work ... Can you tell me how we should solve this problem?
I want the window to open and contain a textarea element.

Comment: What went wrong? Is there a console error? Did you do any debugging?

Comment: @RinoRaj there is already a fiddle in the question of the OP

Comment: Your fiddle is missing a reference to jqueryui https://jsfiddle.net/bac8qdq1/1/

Comment: The "duplicate" is about creating a sliding model, this question is about creating a new window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution. Yo can try

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#OpenDialog").click(function () {
                //$("#dialog").dialog({modal: true, height: 590, width: 1005 });
                var w = window.open("", "popupWindow", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");
                var $w = $(w.document.body);
                $w.html("<textarea></textarea>");
            });
        });
```

Here is the edited jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bac8qdq1/13/

Comment: I think it's not good to fiddle link

Comment: Hey sorry for the wrong link. I updated it

Comment: Otherwise you have to use jquery ui as reference. You fiddle is not using that.

Comment: Amen brother! I took the three lines inside the click handler and it worked beautifully

Answer (score 4):

I have update the fiddle for you, please take a look. It is working

https://jsfiddle.net/bac8qdq1/12/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, height: 590, width: 1005 });

            $("#OpenDialog").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog('open');
            });
        });
```

Comment: also, I have added jqueryui, css. please make sure that you have added that.

Answer (score 1):

To open `dialog` use `open` option:

```
$("#OpenDialog").click(function () {
    $(".selector").dialog("open");
});
```

Docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open

You can also use `autoOpen` option to open dialog on initialization:

```
$("#OpenDialog").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 590,
        width: 1005,
        autoOpen: true
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^
    });
});
```

Docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen

Answer (score 1):

Or even [without JavaScript](https://jsfiddle.net/bac8qdq1/14/). Just for fun.

```
#dialog{
  display: none;
}
#dialog:target{
  display: block;
}
#close{
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
}
#close:target + #dialog{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank for this, It is good. Do you know is it support by all browsers, like IE 7-11, chrome, firefox, opera, safari?

Comment: My pleasure. There is nothing new, so it should works well in all browsers.